# How to filter array and subarray items with identical filter

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have the model below and I need to filter the main array and items subarray by role when one is present.

```
this.model = [
        {label: 'Home', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home', routerLink: ['/main']},
        {label: 'Apps', icon:'pi pi pi-fw pi-desktop', routerLink: ['/main/admin'], role: 's_user',
            items: [
                {label: 'Steve', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-desktop', url: ['ExtURLPlaceholder'], role: 's_user' },
                {label: 'Roger', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-desktop', url: ['ExtURLPlaceholder'] },
            ]},
        {label: 'Admin', icon:'pi pi pi-fw pi-list', routerLink: ['/main/admin'], role: 'y_admin',
            items: [
                {label: 'Susbsystems', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-id-card', routerLink: ['/main/admin/subsystems']},
                {label: 'Logs', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark', routerLink: ['/uikit/floatlabel'], role: 's_user' },
            ]},
        ];
```

I'm able to filter the top level array like this:

```
 this.model = this.model.filter((item)=>{
      if(item.role){
        const token = this.oauthService.getAccessToken();
        return this.jwtService.isAuthorized(token, [item.role])
      }
      return true
    })
```

How can I also filter the items subarray in the same way?

The desired result would return all the items and subitems that match the role requirement if they have a role defined, and filter out those that don't if they have a role defined.

Comment: you can not filter a nested array, because you need to either mutate the children or get only the parents filtered. please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to demonstrate a solution:

```js
let model = [
  {label: 'Home', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home', routerLink: ['/main']},
  {label: 'Apps', icon:'pi pi pi-fw pi-desktop', routerLink: ['/main/admin'], role: 's_user',
      items: [
          {label: 'Steve', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-desktop', url: ['ExtURLPlaceholder'], role: 's_user' },
          {label: 'Roger', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-desktop', url: ['ExtURLPlaceholder'] },
      ]},
  {label: 'Admin', icon:'pi pi pi-fw pi-list', routerLink: ['/main/admin'], role: 'y_admin',
      items: [
          {label: 'Susbsystems', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-id-card', routerLink: ['/main/admin/subsystems']},
          {label: 'Logs', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark', routerLink: ['/uikit/floatlabel'], role: 's_user' },
      ]},
  ];

function filter(item) {
  if (['Apps', 'Steve'].includes(item.label) ) { // keep it?
    if (item.items) {
      item.items = item.items.filter(filter) // apply filter to subarray
    }
    console.log(item)
    return true
  }
  return false // else filter it out
}

model = model.filter(filter)
```

As a demonstration this will keep only "Apps" with only "Steve" in its subarray.

Comment: Not quite what I need.  I need to filter all the model nodes and their sub-nodes using the same filtering scheme, but retain the model structure for the nodes that remain.